# Set notation for an interval or range

Tags: notation, interval-arithmetic

For all **real numbers** between 0 and 1 (closed interval), we can write $[0,1]$ or $\{x\in \mathbb{R} : 0\leq x \leq 1\}$.

For all **integers** between 0 and 1 (closed interval), we can write $[0 .. 1]$ or $\{x\in \mathbb{Z} : 0\leq x \leq 1\}$. Alternatively, we can write $\{0,1\}$.

However, I  find writing the interval as [0,1] can sometimes be a little ambiguous as some refer it to an integer interval. Hence would the following notations serve as valid and natural alternatives?

$\mathbb{R}[0,1]$ or $[0,1]_\mathbb{R}$

$\mathbb{Z}[0,1]$ or $[0,1]_\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[0,1]$ would be interpreted as $\mathbb{R} * [0,1]$. $[0,1]_\mathbb{R}$ should be ok, and I think I have seen that occasionally.